# How to resolve org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.feature.group not found

Tags: java, c, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In eclipse, I install a new Software via help>install NewSoftware > Add. In "Add Repository" dialog, fill Location address.  The installation fails and with below message:

```
The error message is: Missing requirement: **** requires 'org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.feature.group 7.0.0201102110609' but it could not be found
```

How can I resolve this issue. I google org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.feature.group but it does not tell me which plugins should I install...

The eclipse version is:

```
   Eclipse IDE for java Developers
Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what software are you installing (ie. what is the location url)?

Comment: I am using eclipse. It is  "Eclipse IDE for Java develops Version: Indigo Service Release 2 build id: 20120216-1857"

Comment: no, what new software are you installing when you do `Help>Install New Software > Add`

Comment: `org.eclipse.cdt` is the C/C++ development tooling, whatever you are trying to install requires CDT to be installed first.

Comment: It is non-public debug tool, developed by one company. Someone gives me a local copy for trial.. But installation fails due to this dependence failure.  I think if I installed org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.feature.group, the tool installation would success.

Comment: Then you have your answer, no? Add the missing dependency to your repository or get its URL and install it first...

Comment: NO.. I dont have answer.. I don't know where to obtain org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.feature.group dependence and how to install. It seems org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.feature.group is only one feature of some plugins. This maybe the reason that I fail to find it via google.

Comment: See the link in my answer below. I think that may be what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the required software in the exception (`org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.feature.group 7.0.0201102110609`). You probably require software from the CDT Project. Check [here](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php) for download. When you install new software be sure to check the option `Check all update sites during install to find required software` and also install any required modules.

[See here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5bVq.png)

(Note I'm using Juno so the dialog may be different).

Comment: Right. I am missing this dependence. But where can I obtain it?

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this link in my computer, but always fail, reporting connection timeout issue. But everything is ok now when I tried in another PC. Maybe it is some PC configuration issue. Thanks